# Creating nested folders in R

Tags: r

I have done what I need separately in different functions but need help to combine them. I have a list of bank names (10 different banks) in a columns of a data frame. For each bank, I want R to:

1. Create a folder and name the folder using the *BankName* - I use `split()` and `Map()` to do so,
2. Create three different *Level* folders inside each bank folder (namely: "_Lev1","_Lev2","_Lev3") - I use for loop as attached below to do so,
3. Create four different *Grade* folders inside each Level folder (namely: "_G1","_G2","_G3","_G4") - I also use for loop as attached below to do so,

In the current situation, I am able to do all of the three requests separately but not nested, what I need help with is how to combine the above functions to create the nested folders? The results should include, for example,: BankName1 includes three *Level* folders, the three *Level* folders should include the *Grade* folders.

```
Banks_name = paste0('BankName_', 1:10)
Banks_ID = paste0('ID_', 1:10)
df = data.frame(Banks_name, Banks_ID)

# I use split() and Map() to do task#1:
list_Banks = split(df1, df1$BankName)
Map(write.xlsx, list_Banks, paste0(names(list_Banks), 'Bank_.xlsx'))

# I use for() to do task#2:
Levels <- c("_G1","_G2","_G3")
for (j in seq_along(Levels)){
  folder<-dir.create(paste0("~/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Levels",Levels[j]))}

# I also use for() to do task#3:
Grades <- c("_G1","_G2","_G3")
for (j in seq_along(Grades)){
  folder<-dir.create(paste0("~/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Grades",Grades[j]))}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `file.path()` is safer than simple pasting as it is idependent of OS.

There's a typo in your definition of `Levels`, I think.

```
Levels <- c("_L1","_L2","_L3")

# Edit as required for your purposes
rootFolder <- "."
for (b in Banks_name) {
  dir.create(file.path(rootFolder, b))
  for (l in Levels) {
    dir.create(file.path(rootFolder, b, l))
    for (g in Grades) {
      dir.create(file.path(rootFolder, b, l, g))
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine - thanks very much. I just added *df1* right before *BankName*.

Answer (score 2):

I would split the task into two parts:

1. Generate the full path names
2. Create the folders

If we had to create folders recursively I would probably approach this differently (as shown in Limey’s answer) but the `dir.create` function allows us to create nested directories in one go, so we can pass it a path and it creates the full hierarchy; e.g. `dir.create("does/not/exist", recursive = TRUE)` creates the folders `does`, `does/not` and `does/not/exist` all at once.

To solve (1), `expand.grid` provides a very elegant tool. Unfortunately the result type is a bit unwieldy to work with. We can avoid it here by judicious use of the `rep` function:

```
bank_names = paste0('BankName_', 1 : 10)
levels = paste0('_Lev', 1 : 3)
grades = paste0('_G', 1 : 4)

full_paths = file.path(
  banks,
  rep(levels, each = length(banks)),
  rep(grades, each = length(banks) * length(levels))
)
```

And now you can loop over `full_paths` once, and call `dir.create` on each item.

Comment: A good point about recursive folder creation.  I had forgotten that.  It would reduce the length of my solution by two lines.  Every little helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since the combinations are known in advance and are the same for all the banks you can create all of these from the start and then you can loop over just one object.

```
Banks_name = paste0('BankName_', 1:10)
Banks_ID = paste0('ID_', 1:10)
df1 = data.frame(Banks_name, Banks_ID)

tmp=expand.grid(
  df1$Banks_name,
  c("_Lev1","_Lev2","_Lev3"),
  c("_G1","_G2","_G3")
)

for (i in seq_along(row.names(tmp))) {
  paste0(unlist(tmp[i,]),collapse="/")
}
```

and put in the write commands.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I agree about the missing `)`.  You're also probably correct about the naming of the folders.  But OP hasn't provided explicit details of their expected output, so that's understandable.  I've made similar potentially incorrect assumptions in my answer.

Comment: I fixed the `)`, it is an incomplete answer as I suspect this might be self-study.